# Mocking a CloudBlockBlob and have it return a stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-storage, moq

I'm trying to Moq an Azure `CloudBlockBlob` and have it return a `Stream` so that I can test whether my `BlobStorage` repository is handling the output correctly.

But somehow the returned stream is always empty.

Unit test code:

```
//....

var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write("sample data");
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;

var blobMock = new Mock<CloudBlockBlob>(new Uri("http://tempuri.org/blob"));
blobMock
    .Setup(m => m.ExistsAsync())
    .ReturnsAsync(true);
blobMock
    .Setup(m => m.DownloadToStreamAsync(It.IsAny<MemoryStream>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(stream));

//....
```

Repository code:

```
//....

var blob = GetContainer(container).GetBlockBlobReference(name);
if (await blob.ExistsAsync())
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return ms;
}

//....
```

So my returned `MemoryStream ms` is always an empty stream and not the `stream` object I'm using in my Moq `Returns()` method.

How can I have that blob return my sample stream?

Comment: Those are two different streams. Grab the stream passed in the argument of the mock and copy the test stream over.

Comment: Isn't `DownloadToStreamAsync` copying my sample stream over to `ms` then?

Comment: No it is not. And also that method returns a plain Task. Not the stream itself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are two different streams. Grab the stream passed in the argument of the mock in a `Callback` and copy the test stream over.

For example

```
//....
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write("sample data");
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;

var blobMock = new Mock<CloudBlockBlob>(new Uri("http://tempuri.org/blob"));
blobMock
    .Setup(m => m.ExistsAsync())
    .ReturnsAsync(true);
blobMock
    .Setup(m => m.DownloadToStreamAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>()))
    .Callback((Stream target) => stream.CopyTo(target)) //<---Something like this
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
//....
```

The mock does not actually return a stream. It is suppose to act on the stream, which is why the callback is needed to replicated the expected behavior.

Take note

> Copying begins at the current position in the current stream, and does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.

So in that case you might want to reset it if the intention was to read from the target

```
//...

.Callback((Stream target) => {
    stream.CopyTo(target);
    target.Position = 0;
})

//...
```

Comment: tnx, that works indeed! Guess I have some reading up to do on Moq

Comment: I am getting excetpion ....Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (Stream,AccessCondition,FileRequestOptions,OperationContext) cannot invoke callback with parameters (Stream). In my case I am mocking CloudFile

Comment: Missed to add other parameters to the callback method.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61498758/azure-cloudfile-downloadtostream-method-mocking-with-callback-not-working/61498979#61498979